# How do I make canvas shapes fade and disappear over time?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a few different shapes (I only included the code for the triangle since they're all the same) that are generated when the user spins the mouse wheel, but I can't figure out how to make them disappear over time so that the screen doesn't just get completely filled up quickly. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var canvas;
    var context;
    var triangles = [];
    var timer;

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        resizeCanvas();
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);
        canvas.onwheel = function(event) {
            handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        };
        var timer = setInterval(resizeCanvas, 30);
    }

    function Triangle(x,y,triangleColor) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.triangleColor = triangleColor;

            this.vx = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
            this.vy = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
    }

function handleClick(x,y) {
        var colors = ['red','yellow','blue','purple','green'];
        var triangleColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        triangles.push(new Triangle(x,y,triangleColor));
        for (var i=0; i<triangles.length; i++) {
            drawTriangle(triangles[i]);
        }
}

function drawTriangle(triangle) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(triangle.x,triangle.y); 
            context.lineTo(triangle.x+25,triangle.y+25);
            context.lineTo(triangle.x+25,triangle.y-25);
            context.fillStyle = triangle.triangleColor;
            context.fill();
}

function resizeCanvas() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth-20;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight-20;
        fillBackgroundColor();
        for (var i=0; i<triangles.length; i++) {
            var t = triangles[i];
            drawTriangle(t);

            if (t.x + t.vx > canvas.width || t.x + t.vx < 0)
                t.vx = -t.vx
            if (t.y + t.vy > canvas.height || t.y + t.vy < 0)
                t.vy = -t.vy

            t.x += t.vx;
            t.y += t.vy;
        }
}

function fillBackgroundColor() {
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

    window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should triangles fade out after a number of seconds automatically, or should there be a maximum number of triangles at a time, where the first one drawn is the first to disappear?

Comment: They should fade out after a number of seconds automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added time as a property of the triangle object:

```
function Triangle(x,y,triangleColor) {
    ...
    this.time = 100;
}
```

and based it's opacity on the amount of time:

```
function drawTriangle(triangle) {
    ...
    var c = triangle.triangleColor
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + c[0] + ', ' + c[1] + ', ' + c[2] + ', ' + (triangle.time / 100) + ')';
```

Once the time runs out the triangle is removed from the list:

```
function resizeCanvas() {
    ...
    if(t.time === 0) {
        triangles.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

Also, to make it easier to draw the shapes using rgba values I converted the colors variable from an array of strings to an array of an array of their rgb values:

```
var colors = [[255,0,0],[255,255,0],[0,0,255],[128,0,128],[0,255,0]];
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the implementation:

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lh1ydb2/1/

Comment: This works great thank you!! However, is there a way using this code to make the fade less gradual? So that the triangle stays solid for longer and then fades quicker towards the end?

Comment: Sure. There are probably a few ways to it. I updated the jsfiddle with the first method that came to my head (by starting the triangles with a larger time, decreasing the time faster, and creating a function to convert time to alpha value). It is a little sloppy, but it should be pretty easy to adjust for your needs.